# Build Visual Studio project fails - The cloud operation was unsuccessful

Tags: share, onedrive

I'm using two laptops and stored my C# code in OneDrive.
I am aware that sharing code via OneDrive is not be the best approach, but that's what I'm dealing with now.

I noticed that on laptop 1 I have to define the following path to the data file (mdf):

- C:\Users\ **Diet**\OneDrive\Personal\VisualStudio2019\Repos\project\project\App_Data\data.mdf

On laptop 2, the path is different because the user I'm logged in with has a different name (or at least that's what I believe is the cause)

- C:\Users\ **Dieter**\OneDrive\Personal\VisualStudio2019\Repos\project\project\App_Data\data.mdf

Updating this in the Web.config fixed the connection to the database, BUT building the solution still returns an error, also related to a cloud operation, hence why I think it is caused by the path in OneDrive...

The error message:

```
CSC : error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'The cloud operation was unsuccessful.
```

I welcome your insights. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have my projects stored in OneDrive and had this same issue. The fix was to set the entire Project folder contents to "Always keep on this device".

Seems that building the solution in VS was attempting to write to files that were not cached locally from OneDrive. As soon as I changed the setting, the build worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was also storing my project on OneDrive, got the same error after installing a new ssd.

Rebuilding the solution was enough for me.