# Visual Studio Project On OneDrive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, onedrive

I am currently working on a small console app to try to slowly get back into coding

Nothing special working on converting an file to byte array and storing this in another folder within the project, pretty straight forward.
However when attempting access the test file or even save the converted file to a folder within the project im getting errors

I thought everything would go as normal but I got the following error

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\gavin\OneDrive\Documents\Portfolio\ByteConverter\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConvertedToByte\test'.'

Now tested this same function on my local c drive and ran into no errors
I would like to keep things on my OneDrive but is this not possible or will I need to enable a feature within Visual studio Im not aware of?

Edit:
I forgot to include my code, apologies this has been pointed out and I will go ahead and include it here

```
Using System.IO;

namespace BystConverter
{
    
    public class converter
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

> (Error exception occurs here v)

```
          File.WriteAllBytes("ConvertedToByte/test",SaveByteArrayToFile("C:/Users/gavin/Documents/Testfiles/925821-DDAL_08-02_Beneath_the_City_of_the_Dead_V1.0.pdf"));
```

> 

```
            Console.WriteLine("Complete");
        }
        public static byte[] SaveByteArrayToFile(string filepath)
        {
            byte[] filebyteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
            return filebyteArray;
        }
        
}


}
```

Comment: I think you need some authentication process in order to manipulate OneDrive files

Comment: You should provide your code around where the exception is thrown.

Comment: OneDrive is not a substitute for an actual version-control system. OneDrive does not guarantee any ability to _snapshot_ the directory, and it's incredibly difficult to exclude specific directories (like `bin`, `node_modules`, etc). VS is designed to work with `git` (and other MSSCCI-compliant system), not OneDrive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235446/build-visual-studio-project-fails-the-cloud-operation-was-unsuccessful

Comment: FWIW: I've never had a good experience mixing Visual Studio with One Drive (home or business). Take @Dai's suggestion and use source control to manage things

Comment: Thank you @Dai , this is the best explanation and would explain why its not working, I think going forward I will keep my projects on the local drive.

Comment: @GavWasTaken Hi, I posted Dai's comment as an answer. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

As Dai said OneDrive is not a replacement for an actual version control system. OneDrive does not guarantee the ability to snapshot directories, and excluding specific directories (like bin, node_modules, etc.) is very difficult. VS is designed to be used with git (and other MSSCCI compliant systems), not with OneDrive.

You can try using a formal version control system: Git

Please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/version-control/?view=vs-2022